# How can we efficiently count the digits in an integer in Elixir?

Tags: count, elixir, digits

How can we efficiently count the digits in an integer in Elixir?

My attempt in Iex

```
iex(1)> a=100_000                                               
100000
iex(2)> Enum.reduce(1..a, &(&1*&2))|> to_string|> String.length
456574
iex(3)>
```

Takes ***over*** 15 seconds

Another Implementation:

```
defmodule Demo do
    def cnt(n), do: _cnt(n,0)
    defp _cnt(0,a), do: a
    defp _cnt(n,a),do: _cnt(div(n,10),a+1)
end
```

Is way slower: b = 100_000!

***A suggestion from the comments (Thanks Fred!)***

```
iex> Integer.to_char_list(b) |> length
```

Is best so far and simplest

```
IEx> :timer.tc(fn -> Demo.cnt b  end)
{277662000, 456574}
IEx> :timer.tc(fn ->b |> to_string |> String.length end) 
{29170000, 456574}
```

Is there built in *wizardry* for this in any Elixir module?

Comment: Hint: math.log10(10) = 1; math.log10(100) = 2; math.log10(789) = 2.897. Can you see the relationship between the log to base 10 of a number and the number of digits? You will also want to use the floor function.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks, i think i get your suggestion

Comment: @AndrewMorton no math module or log function in Elixir that i can readily find

Comment: Apparently you can use libraries from Erlang - search for "elixir math library". I know nothing about Elixir. Oh, and instead of `floor` it appears that you can use `trunc` to be more succinct.

Comment: @AndrewMorton nah.... 308 digit limit

Comment: Lol, there are reckoned to be [less than 10^90 neutrinos in the universe](http://timeblimp.com/?page_id=1031) (they outnumber the [photons](http://www.quora.com/How-many-photons-are-there-in-the-universe)) - do you *really* need to be able to work with numbers larger than 10^308?

Comment: The computation of the number itself already takes over 7 seconds on my machine, so another 8-ish seconds to count the digit seems not too bad...

Comment: @AndrewMorton what's the size of the visible universe measured in plank lengths? ... my point is you might not have a conceivable application for such a large number now, but you can never tell

Comment: FWIW using to_char_list and length is slightly faster. `iex(10)>  :timer.tc( fn -> Integer.to_string(b_fact) |> String.length end )
{16825611, 456574}`
`iex(11)>  :timer.tc( fn -> Integer.to_char_list(b_fact) |> length end )
{16704290, 456574}`

Comment: Your Demo function is perfect. Why do you say it is slower? It is instant and faster than all other solutions discussed in theory and in my machine. :)

Comment: @JoséValim it is amazingly lower - for some reason, have you  tried the test value of b= 100000!

Comment: @JoséValim what timing did you get ? better than {277662000, 456574} ?

Comment: @CharlesO in reference to Andrew Morton's suggestion--we don't bother to recreate functionality in Elixir that already exists in Erlang.  http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/math.html

Comment: One small, dumb suggestion @CharlesO on code formatting: a = 100_000 works just as well as the other way and it's easier to read. Using the "_" as a separator makes no difference to Elixir but it makes it less likely that someone will miscount the zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Elixir 1.1 and above there is now a built in feature

```
Integer.digits/2
```

This effectively handles digit counting

Comment: To be more specific, to get the Integer length, you need to do

```ex
number |> Integer.digits() |> length()
```